# Flutter Futurebuilder snapshot is null

Tags: json, listview, flutter, dart, future

I try to show the results from JSON in a ListView in Flutter with a FutureBuilder.
But the snapshot is null and the message that no data is available shows.

Here I try to fetch the data:

```
static Future _getBans() async {
Storage.getLoggedToken().then((token) async {
  var body = {
    "token": token
  };
  final response = await http.post('${URLS.BASE_URL}/punishments.php', headers: ApiService.header, body: json.encode(body));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {

    List<Ban> bans = [];
    var jsonData = json.decode(response.body)["bans"];
    for(var b in jsonData){
      Ban ban = Ban(b["player"], b["reason"], int.parse(b["end"]), b["by"]);
      bans.add(ban);
    }

    print(response.body);
    print(bans.length);

    return bans;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
});
```

}

from this JSON response

```
{"status":1,"msg":"OK","bans":[{"player":"DDOSAttacke","reason":"Hacking","end":"1579275471304","by":"DDOSAttacke"}],"mutes":[]}
```

My Futurebuilder. Here is snapshot null but the count of the elements is working.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Aktive Bans'),
  ),
  body: Container(
    child: FutureBuilder(
      future: _getBans(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.data == null) {
          return Container(
            child: Center(
                child: Text('Keine aktiven Ban vorhanden')
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(snapshot.data[index].player),
              );
            },
          );
        }
      },
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

Comment: wait, you mean that `AsyncSnapshot snapshot` is null? or `snapshot.data`?

Comment: I mean snapshot.data

Comment: maybe because of: `} else {
    return null;
  }`?

Comment: I have tried it and the same result

Comment: so do you return non `null` value from `_getBans()` method? are you sure?

Comment: Yes. Then I print the length before the return with ```print(bans.length);``` and I will get the current length.

Comment: I see this two lines flutter: AsyncSnapshot<dynamic>(ConnectionState.waiting, null, null) and flutter: AsyncSnapshot<dynamic>(ConnectionState.done, null, null)

Comment: Yes, I get ```hello world``` as ```snap.data```. But how I can get my fetched data in the Futurebuilder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this. I think you'll have to use `await` keyword for the `getLoggedToken` mothod, the `return`will wait for the post before returning anything. But now you're returning before the `getLoggedToken`finishes his work. That is why you are always receiving null.

```
 static Future _getBans() async {
 var token = await Storage.getLoggedToken();
      var body = {
        "token": token
      };
      final response = await http.post('${URLS.BASE_URL}/punishments.php', headers: ApiService.header, body: json.encode(body));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {

    List<Ban> bans = [];
    var jsonData = json.decode(response.body)["bans"];
    for(var b in jsonData){
      Ban ban = Ban(b["player"], b["reason"], int.parse(b["end"]), b["by"]);
      bans.add(ban);
    }

    print(response.body);
    print(bans.length);

    return bans;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please help me resolve this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67813247/flutter-futurebuilder-snapshot-is-null-after-database-query-until-hot-reload